# Store a field of multiple Booleans

Tags: php, mysql, json

My point is the following:
I have a MySQL DB where events are stored. These events could be on different days of the week. You could say it looks like the following:

```
Day | Active
Mon | yes
Tue | yes
Wed | no
Thu | no
Fri | yes
Sat | no
Sun | no
```

Now I'm not entirely sure on how I could save this into the DB. Of course there are several possibilities but I see disadvantages on everything I could think of:

- Store them as 7 fields of type Bool (Seems to be a lot of fields for something like that)
- Store them as an 7-bit number (This way I would just need an Integer, but this would need some effort to transform and lacks readability)

In C++ these data could be stored into a std::bitset. I bet there is something which could be used for this in MySQL... Please point me to it :)

PS:
I don't know if it is important: The data will be read with PHP and served as JSON to the outer world.

Comment: you could use the `SET` datatype http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an SET type (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html). For example, that's what you table might look like:

```
+-------------+--------------------+
| event_name  | days               |
+-------------+--------------------+
| some event  | 'monday,friday'    |
+-------------+--------------------+
| another one | 'tuesday'          |
+-------------+--------------------+
```

It is easy to select rows from that kind of table and it's really readable for anyone lurking in the database.

Comment: +1 . . . This is the best approach in MySQL.  Sets are not portable to other databases.  They are also limited in the number of different elements.  But, they seem very well suited to something like the days of the week.

Comment: I think this will be the way to go. When encoded to JSON the events will just have a list of days when they will be activated.

Answer (score 2):

you should prolly use the int idea. In your php you can define the masks as constants, and than use bitwise operations to figure out which flags are set.

So rather than doing something like

```
myvar & 0x010
```

it would look more like you are operating with a constant

```
myvar & IS_MONDAY
```

Comment: while the constant idea is a good one, why use mysql `INT` when the SET datatype can accept bitmasks already?

Comment: The INT-method has the advantage of being portable, while using SET is not portable (as Stormherz said). The disadvantage in my eyes is the readability. Additionally I would have to implement the en/decoding myself, which could be a source of error.

Answer (score 0):

If your entry is merely to store weekly events with the input you provided, why not create a VARCHAR field and store it as a JSON string:
    { "Mon":"yes", "Tue":"yes", "Wed":"no", "Thu":"no", "Fri":"yes", "Sat":"no", "Sun":"no" }

Comment: Because then I could simply store everything in VARCHAR-fields, this is not what I want when I decide to use a database like MySQL. Some disadvantages I could think of would be searchability, bad performance, difficult to enhance, ...